# Create re-runnable Postgresql DDL scripts

Tags: postgresql, ddl, postgresql-9.6

I want to create re-runnable DDL script for PostgreSQL database.  I have done this for SQL server using SSMS. SSMS can generate DDL statements for a database with "if not exists" condition.

How can we do this for PostgreSQL?
I want to generate DDL statements for one of my PostgreSQL database and want to run it on another database so that I can create all the tables on target database also. However, DDL Script should have "IF Not EXISTS" for each table so that I don't get any error if the script is run multiple times.

Is there any tool which can automatically create Such DDL Statements for a database for Postgresql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Idempotent PostgreSQL DDL scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731851/idempotent-postgresql-ddl-scripts)

Comment: Nearly every DDL statement has an `IF NOT EXISTS` and `IF EXISTS` option. The other option is to use tools like [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/)

Comment: Take a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44804538/7925366).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: i know that we can use if not exists statements manually, But I want to generate DDL scripts which contains conditional if statements so that i don't get an error while running script multiple time. is there any tool available which can do this?

Comment: Now, find a way to conditionally execute `ALTER TABLE ...` DDL statements.

Comment: It's a bad idea, there are way too many cases where there's no sensible outcome. What if step 1 `ADD`s column "x" then step 2 `RENAME`s it to "y". When you rerun step 1... oops. Use schema versioning instead.

Comment: @CraigRinger : We don't run backward incompatible SQL queries like Renaming a column.