# How to pass PSQL variables to the PASSWORD option of CREATE USER?

Tags: postgresql, shell, variables, command-line-arguments, psql

I have a do block in a sql script **(create-user.sql)** as below, to create a user

```
do $$
begin
 create user :user_name with password ':pass';
exception
 when duplicate_object then
   raise notice 'user already exists';
end$$
```

I want to pass user_name and 'pwd' to this script , so I used the -v option

```
psql --host="myhost" --port=5432 --username=connectionuser --dbname=xyz -v user_name=myuser -v pass=mypass -f create-user.sql
```

When I execute the command, it throws me an error

***syntax error at or near ":"***

How do I pass variables to the sql script ?
I have even tried := instead of : , but similar error is thrown

Comment: I guess [`createuser`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createuser.html) is not helpful here because it doesn't have a password argument - maybe with piping though?

Comment: 1) You have `pwd` in the script but `pass` in the command line. 2) Why `:'pwd'` instead of just `:pwd`?

Comment: psql variables are not interpolated  in strings delimited by `$$`. You'll have to generate your SQL statement differently.

Comment: @Matt: I've updated it correctly now. It is a password field, so it has to be in ' ' as per the syntax.

Comment: @DanielVérité is correct. If you take your `create user` statement out of the anonymous block, so it is the only statement in the file, it works. Maybe make a function/sp and then execute that from psql?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
psql -qf setup-postgres.sql                                            
    --set POSTGRES_USERNAME=$POSTGRES_USERNAME                         
    --set DATOMIC_USERNAME=$POSTGRES_DATOMIC_USERNAME                  
    --set DATOMIC_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_DATOMIC_PASSWORD                  
    postgresql://$POSTGRES_USERNAME:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@datomic-postgres.internal
```

setup-postgres.sql:

```
SET client_min_messages TO WARNING;

CREATE DATABASE datomic WITH
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    OWNER = :"POSTGRES_USERNAME"
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    TEMPLATE template0
;

\c datomic

SET DATOMIC.USERNAME TO :"DATOMIC_USERNAME";
SET DATOMIC.PASSWORD TO :'DATOMIC_PASSWORD';

DO $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('CREATE ROLE %I LOGIN PASSWORD %L'
        , current_setting('DATOMIC.USERNAME')
        , current_setting('DATOMIC.PASSWORD')
    );
EXCEPTION
    WHEN duplicate_object THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'User already exists. Ignoring...';
END$$;

DO $$
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE datomic_kvs (
        id text NOT NULL,
        rev integer,
        map text,
        val bytea,
        CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
    WITH (
        OIDS = FALSE
    );
EXCEPTION
    WHEN duplicate_table THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Table already exists. Ignoring...';
END$$;

ALTER TABLE datomic_kvs
    OWNER TO :"POSTGRES_USERNAME";

GRANT ALL ON TABLE datomic_kvs
    TO :"POSTGRES_USERNAME";
GRANT ALL ON TABLE datomic_kvs
    TO public;
```

Oddly, the variable names in the SET commands, e.g. `DATOMIC.USERNAME`, must include a `.`